# jQuery sort elements by position in page

Tags: jquery, sorting, javascript-objects

I want to sort elements by position in the page. Meaning if I have an object:

$obj = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');

But my markup is like:

```
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

How would I sort $obj to be $('#div3, #div1, #div2');

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery does that for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/PHW7C/

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you I found this out the hard way. facepalm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if they start with a same prefix you can do something like this

```
$obj = $('[id^=div]');
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wytXQ/

Comment: Well, what I didn't know is that jQuery sorts the list by default in order. So even if you create your object in reverse order it still is stored in the order in which the page loads top to bottom. Thanks for the answer.